# Padding with position:absolute and position:relative not working

Tags: html, css, dom

Here is the css

```
.column_transparent_div {
    background-color: rgba(46, 47, 48, 0.45);
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px; /* have 20px padding on the right and left hand side */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.project_div {
    position: absolute; /* when I remove this line, it works fine */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "title          github"
        "project_text   project_text"
        ".              read_more"
    ;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
}
```

When I have position:absolute enabled then the padding works on the left hand side but not the right hand side. If I delete position:absolute then the padding works on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The padding belongs to the parent element. When you use position absolute, you're removing the child element from the parent and positioning it relative to the start of the parent. I see two options.

**Option 1:** You could use top, bottom, left, and right to move the element.

```css
.project_div {
  top: 0; 
  right 20px;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 20px;
}
```

**Option 2:** You could add a wrapping `div` and position relative to the new element.

```css
.column_transparent_div {
  background-color: rgba(46, 47, 48, 0.45);
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.project_div {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 25px 0 25px
  0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_transparent_div">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="project_div">
      .project_div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```